# Javascript: Mouse follow & mouse hover animation with ACF & Elementor Pro

Tags: javascript, advanced-custom-fields, event-listener, elementor

I'm creating a new website in Elementor Pro, based on a design earlier made within Figma.

For some parts I'd need some extra coding I'm struggling with. This coding should work within Elementor Pro and should partly take images/data from Advanced Custom Fields.

1. I've got a full height & width image background container on Elementor. When hovering over this container a mouse following button should appear, linking towards another page.

Design idea: https://snipboard.io/prlKZG.jpg

I've found the behaviour I'm looking for on another website, screen movie here: https://www.loom.com/share/899d13564f474df7aa0db0172cd8af13?sid=59f092b5-2bba-4a30-804c-bf3b192adc3c

2. The same behaviour should happen when hovering over brand logo's. These brands are loaded as Custom Post Type with the help of Advanced Custom Fields.
   When hovering over the logo's, this time it should not be 'just a button' showing up, but it should be an image. This image is set on the corresponding brand within an ACF image field.

Design idea:
https://snipboard.io/aAPd9V.jpg

The red part on the screenshot is the part that should be created - ACF and everything else is already created.

I've been trying things with Event Listeners, but can't seem to get things working.

Could you help me out in the right direction here?

Thanks!

I've been trying things with Event Listeners, but can't seem to get things working.